# Executing asynchronous functions in order, and waiting for for every function to be finished

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to execute a few async functions in a specific order and also wait for every function until it finish.
I'm doing like this:

```
public async init(): Promise<void> {
try {
 this.executeFunction1().then(() => {
    this.executeFunction2().then(() => {
      this.executeFunction3().then(() => {
        this.executeFunction4().then(() => {
          this.executeFunction5();
        });
      });
    });
  });
} catch (error) {
  this.log.error(`Init failed`);
}
```

}

All functions are async like:

```
  public async executeFunction1(): Promise<void> {
   ...........................
  }
```

Is this a good way (best practice) or is this way is 'Ok'/'not advised' but there is a better way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a trivial `async`/`await` case. Since you're already using `async`, you're missing the `await`s. Something like this will do:

```
public async init(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        await this.executeFunction1();
        await this.executeFunction2();
        await this.executeFunction3();
        await this.executeFunction4();
        await this.executeFunction5();
    } catch (error) {
        this.log.error(`Init failed`);
    }
}
```

This kind of programming is the prime reason why `async`/`await` was introduced, to facilitate async calls in a pseudo sync way.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use RxJS you can use `concat` creation method:

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

concat(
  this.executeFunction1(),
  this.executeFunction2(),
  this.executeFunction3(),
  this.executeFunction4(),
  this.executeFunction5(),
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```js
public async init(): Promise<void> {
  try {
   await this.executeFunction1();
   await this.executeFunction2();
   // etc ...
  } catch (error) {
    this.log.error(`Init failed`);
  }
}
```